# E: Unable to locate package apache2-mpm-prefork for install rapidleech

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I want install rapidleech on ubuntu
after run this command get this error

`sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-mpm-prefor`

E: Unable to locate package apache2-mpm-prefork

and after run this command get this error

`sudo apt-get -y install apache2-prefork-dev apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common apache2`

E: Unable to locate package apache2-prefork-dev
E: Package 'apache2.2-bin' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'apache2.2-common' has no installation candidate

what do I do?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? On my bionic-based system, I get the same error on your first command; on the second, only **apache2** and **apache2-utils** exist.

Comment: my Ubuntu version is 18.10. but now my problem is install this https://github.com/liaralabs/swizzin/blob/master/scripts/nginx/rapidleech.sh. I dont know how install this

Comment: It's just a script - download it, make it executable. This is the extent of my knowledge of **rapidleech**.